# If a then it cannot fail to be the case that b

Tags: logic, necessity

I am studying logic in my free time from the book Logic: A very short introduction by Grahan Priest and I am currently encountering difficulties in chapter 6 about Necessity and possibility.
In this chapter Priest takes about the statement: "If a then it cannot fail to be the case that b". This statement is in fact ambiguous and there are apparantly two ways of interpreting this:

1. If a is true then b is necessarily true
2. If a then it cannot fail to be the case that b.

The author gives an example with a person being married and getting divorced:
If John is getting divorced, he is married;  but it is certainly not true that if John is getting a divorce he is necessarily (irrevocably) married.I don't quite see the difference between the two statements. I am sure it has something to do with the irrevocably.
But where does the "irrevocably" come from?

Comment: Your two interpretations, although stated differently, appear to me to be the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is concerned with the scope of the 'necessarily' operator. There is a difference between "Necessarily: if A then B" and "if A then necessarily B". In the first example it is the conditional that holds necessarily. In the second example, B holds necessarily provided A is true.

The first kind is more common and may be represented in modal logic as □(A → B). The second kind would be A → □B. The significance of the difference is that with the second one, you can take A → □B together with A to detach □B. But with the first you cannot take □(A → B) together with A to detach □B. Doing so is sometimes called the modal fallacy.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect he is trying to draw the distinction between a statement such as 'John is human' or 'two is an even number' and a statement such as 'John is married' and 'two is the number of cakes on that plate'. The first set of statements suggest a permanent, almost definitional relationship, whereas the second set denotes a temporary or contingent relationship.